# Multiple TransListenAddress, DNSListenAddress entries

Tags: configuration

I wanted to know if it's possible to put multiple DNSListenAddress and TransListenAddress entries in the torrc file.
What i want to do is redirect the traffic that comes from clients connected to my vpn server AND from those connected to my wifi hotspot (tor, ovpn and wifi hotspot all installed on my RaspPi) to the tor network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DNSListenAddress` and `TransListenAddress` are deprecated.

Instead use multiple `DNSPort` and `TransPort` entries with explicit addresses specified for each.

Answer (score 0):

(i dont have enough rep to comment in the correct answer)

To the above answer I would add an example. Many deprecated manuals/tutorials as part of the torrc config file point the following:

```
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 192.168.50.1
DNSPort 53
DNSListenAddress 192.168.50.1
```

being 192.168.50.1 the configured AP IP. Since `TransListenAddress` and `DNSListenAddress` are deprecated the configuration should look like this:

```
TransPort 192.168.50.1:9040
DNSPort 192.168.50.1:53
```